# SQLAlchemy event listener to validate field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just want to run python code before the database inserts the data, to be able to validate a string. And since I'm using the https://github.com/encode/databases library I can only use the Core of SQLAlchemy, so I can't declare my table using ORM.

I have the following table:

```py
application_permissions_table = Table(
    "application_permissions",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("acl", String, nullable=False, unique=True),
)
```

I created an event to check the validity of `acl`. I want to be able to use this with PostgreSQL, SQLite and maybe another database.

```py
@event.listens_for(application_permissions_table.c.acl, "set")
def receive_set(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    regex = r"^(Allow|Deny)\|(\w+:\w+|Authenticated)\|\w+$"
    if not re.match(regex, value):
        raise ValueError("ACL don't match the format")
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and gives the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No such event 'set' for target 'application_permissions.acl'`

Comment: You are trying to use an ORM event on SQLAlchemy Core. That's why you get the error. If you define the table as an ORM object and use something like `ApplicationPermission.acl` it should work.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I just updated the question, it is not possible for me to use the ORM object.